# How to disable port 80 and enable port 443 for https in apache2 on Debian?

Tags: debian, ssl, https, apache2

I installed apache2 on my Debian server, and I want to completely disable HTTP over port 80 and only have https over port 443.

This is my current ports.conf file

[ports.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFT0t.png)

This is my 000-default.conf file

[000-default.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpWl8.png)

and this is my default-ssl.conf file

[default-ssl.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2k9y.png)

Basically my end goal is to be able to do an nmap scan of the server and have https over port 443 show up and not have http over port 80 show up at all.

---

Edit: Tried commenting out Listen 80 and everything in the 000-default.conf filed and got the following errors when I tried to restart apache

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z85tk.png)

Comment: look for ports.conf

Comment: @djdomi I took a screenshot of ports.conf and included it in the post. Do I need to change the "Listen 80" to "Listen 443" or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the Listen 80 also comment out all lines on the 000-default.conf and restart

Comment: exactly - thump up you may see apachectl -t to check out the config

Comment: I'll try this out in just a minute and keep you posted!

Comment: When I do this and restart apache I get an error. I edited my post to include it

Comment: @Ryan you should also be sure that you have a valid ssl certificate on your default-ssl.conf

Comment: @TalalAl-Khalifa I forgot to enable the included self-signed certificated and used the command "a2enmod ssl" which enabled the ssl. Restarted apache and now it's working. Thank you!